How to get a JSON output when execute a InfluxDB query in the postman
How to get a JSON output when execute the below Flux query in postman
Flux Query
{
  "type": "flux",
  "spec": {
    "from": {
      "bucket": "prod_jmeter"
    },
    "range": {
      "start": "2020-03-29T07:44:00.341Z",
      "stop": "2054-03-29T07:44:00.341Z"
    },
    "filter": {
      "fn": "(r) => r[\"_measurement\"] == \"requestsRaw\""
    },
    "filter": {
      "fn": "(r) => r[\"_field\"] == \"responseTime\""
    },
    "group": {
      "columns": ["_field"]
    },
    "count": {}
  }
}

Request Headers
Authorization - Token <token_Id>
Accept - application/csv
Content-type - application/json
I am getting the below error message
Error Message
{
    "code": "invalid",
    "message": "failed to decode request body: request body requires either query or AST"
}

